# How to get the key value from response where the position of the key value pair are changing on each request

Tags: jmeter

Have a unique problem, when I request the same api again and again I am getting the same response but the key-value pair of the response are keep on changing values are remain same.

Response 1 on first request:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "customfield-4b7c5fb0-20de-4c4f-aecf-892b585855ab": "Test Schedule",
        "test_additional_history": "(0010,21B0)",
        "test_mother_birthname": "(0010,1060)",
        "customfield-73ee5b7f-5cfb-4cbb-ab09-69583de4b9cc": "Would you like to request an expedited central review to confirm progression?",
        "test_current_location": "(0038,0300)",
        "test_size": "(0010,1020)",
        "customfield-6844b23b-cff0-44b0-b2af-5eda668dc729": "Is this a baseline test?",
        "modality": "(0008,0060)",
        "date": "(0008,0020)",
        "customfield-d52ba358-07c1-428e-a345-b8bcb8d9b314": "Subject Number",
        "test_name": "(0010,0010)",
        "customfield-f049af7b-a550-45dc-8bae-abc27797518f": "Comments",
        "user_occupation": "(0010,2180)",
        "user_birthname": "(0010,1005)",
        "user_size": "(0010,1020)",
        "customfield-5701c632-33a1-4e67-9c34-c0bbf3a82208": "trial_test_name",
        "user_occupation": "(0010,2180)",
        "user_birthname": "(0010,1005)",
        "user_size": "(0010,1020)",
        "customfield-26918767-1b73-413c-835d-ed204f1a3297": "Test Arm",
        "user_mother_birthname": "(0010,1060)",
        "customfield-a5363a01-b8b2-4da2-acfe-bbc2316dbbdd": "Test ID",
        "user_birth_time": "(0010,0032)",
        "customfield-8de944cd-ad93-490a-b34d-f8d248a70997": "Test Start Date",
        "user_address": "(0010,1040)",
        "customfield-5c0bb293-3f4b-42b5-aa49-b121d621a3dd": "Randomization Date",
        "user_description": "(0008,1030)",
        "customfield-d378e755-6da9-4ba5-a8ef-41026272adda": "trial_project_tims",
        "user_record_locator": "(0010,1090)"
    },
    "status": "OK",
    "defaults": {
        "customfield-d378e755-6da9-4ba5-a8ef-41026272adda": "PERF_TEST00004"
    }
}
```

Response 2 on second request:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "defaults": {
        "customfield-d378e755-6da9-4ba5-a8ef-41026272adda": "PERF_TEST00004"
    },
    "fields": {
        "customfield-d52ba358-07c1-428e-a345-b8bcb8d9b314": "Subject Number",
        "test_additional_history": "(0010,21B0)",
        "test_mother_birthname": "(0010,1060)",
        "customfield-d378e755-6da9-4ba5-a8ef-41026272adda": "trial_project_tims",
        "test_current_location": "(0038,0300)",
        "test_size": "(0010,1020)",
        "customfield-26918767-1b73-413c-835d-ed204f1a3297": "Test Arm",
        "modality": "(0008,0060)",
        "date": "(0008,0020)",
        "customfield-8de944cd-ad93-490a-b34d-f8d248a70997": "Test Start Date",
        "test_name": "(0010,0010)",
        "customfield-5701c632-33a1-4e67-9c34-c0bbf3a82208": "trial_test_name",
        "user_occupation": "(0010,2180)",
        "user_birthname": "(0010,1005)",
        "user_size": "(0010,1020)",
        "customfield-5c0bb293-3f4b-42b5-aa49-b121d621a3dd": "Randomization Date",
        "user_mother_birthname": "(0010,1060)",
        "customfield-6844b23b-cff0-44b0-b2af-5eda668dc729": "Is this a baseline test?",
        "user_birth_time": "(0010,0032)",
        "customfield-a5363a01-b8b2-4da2-acfe-bbc2316dbbdd": "Test ID",
        "user_address": "(0010,1040)",
        "customfield-f049af7b-a550-45dc-8bae-abc27797518f": "Comments",
        "user_description": "(0008,1030)",
        "customfield-4b7c5fb0-20de-4c4f-aecf-892b585855ab": "Test Schedule",
        "user_record_locator": "(0010,1090)",
        "customfield-73ee5b7f-5cfb-4cbb-ab09-69583de4b9cc": "Would you like to request an expedited central review to confirm progression?"
    }
}
```

Both the response are identical only the value's place are changed. I want to fetch the `key` of very specific value.

example:

1. "customfield-4b7c5fb0-20de-4c4f-aecf-892b585855ab": "Test Schedule"
2. "customfield-6844b23b-cff0-44b0-b2af-5eda668dc729": "Is this a baseline test?"
3. "customfield-d52ba358-07c1-428e-a345-b8bcb8d9b314": "Subject Number"
4. "customfield-f049af7b-a550-45dc-8bae-abc27797518f": "Comments"
5. "customfield-5701c632-33a1-4e67-9c34-c0bbf3a82208": "trial_test_name"
6. "customfield-26918767-1b73-413c-835d-ed204f1a3297": "Test Arm"
7. "customfield-a5363a01-b8b2-4da2-acfe-bbc2316dbbdd": "Test ID"
8. "customfield-d378e755-6da9-4ba5-a8ef-41026272adda": "trial_project_tims"

Want to fetch all the key value which is,

```
customfield-4b7c5fb0-20de-4c4f-aecf-892b585855ab
customfield-6844b23b-cff0-44b0-b2af-5eda668dc729
customfield-d52ba358-07c1-428e-a345-b8bcb8d9b314
customfield-f049af7b-a550-45dc-8bae-abc27797518f
customfield-5701c632-33a1-4e67-9c34-c0bbf3a82208
customfield-26918767-1b73-413c-835d-ed204f1a3297
customfield-a5363a01-b8b2-4da2-acfe-bbc2316dbbdd
customfield-d378e755-6da9-4ba5-a8ef-41026272adda
```

Used regular expression,
for example for getting the subject number I used

regex: `"date":"(.*?)","(.*?)":"Subject Number"`
$1$
2

Worked first time but failing second time as the position changed. Is there any way like using `JSON Extractor` or any other  with condition to find the keys based upon the value as value will be constant all the time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your output these are the regular expression which should solve your problem,

So according to you the values are constant  and you need the corresponding keys then these expression  will solve your problem,

```
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"Test Schedule"
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"Is this a
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"Subject Number"
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"Comments"
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"trial_test_name"
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"Test Arm"
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"Test ID"
\s*"([^"]*)":?\s*"trial_project_tims"
```

Comment: Yeah this working independently